# Kentico Smart Search results suddenly returns empty

Tags: kentico

I use smart search on my site, and it's been working fine. Today, just heard that the search result page return "No results were found". **The thing is: if I logged into admin (Live site), the search result page showed data, but if I logged out, the results were empty.** The search on my staging site worked fine.

I've been trying to troubleshoot but couldn't. Don't know yet when the issue started. Things I've done and looked at: Visibility, and Security setting applied on the page and web part, re-built Search Index. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Just make it clear: 
*** if you are logged in and to to your search page inside admin: search works;
*** if you are log out and go to the same page on a live site: no results found;
*** but if you are logged in and you go to your search page on  a live site?: What happens?

try to output a couple macros: {%ViewMode%} {%CurrentUser.IsAuthorizedPerResource( "CMS.Search","read") #%}

Just to see if on what it depends. Anything in the event log?

Comment: To clarify: If I log in and do a search inside admin OR on the live site, search results worked in both cases. Using Google analytics, it appears that search stopped working on or after May 10. I'm trying to look into log files, but no results yet.

Comment: I added your macro {%CurrentUser.IsAuthorizedPerResource( "CMS.Search","read") #%}  to the page and the result came back False if not logging in, and True if logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a permission issue. You probably have [the smart search set up to filter out results for pages that users are not allowed to access](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-locally-stored-search-indexes/searching-according-to-page-permissions)

1. Open your web part properties(Smart search results or search dialog with results ) whatever you are using.
2. Scroll down to *Page filter category*
3. Uncheck *Enable Check permissions* checkbox

This checkbox indicates whether the web part filters the search results to exclude pages for which users do not have the "Read" permission.